# Is that valid to use private static callbacks in PHP?

Tags: php

This works:

```
class MyClass {
  private static $data = array( 'banana', 'cherry', 'apple' );

  private static function sort_by_text( $first, $second ) {
    return strcasecmp( $first, $second );
  } 

  public static function sorted_data() {
    usort( self::$data, array( __CLASS__, 'sort_by_text' ) );
    return self::$data;
  }
}

print_r( MyClass::sorted_data() ); 
// Array ( [0] => apple [1] => banana [2] => cherry )
```

But, [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) always use `public` callbacks.

Is the fact that callbacks can be `private` just not documented well, or making them `private` can lead to issues?

Comment: your calling the private method from inside the class so its allowed isn't it?

Comment: @DevZer0: but it's not the method inside the class calling it; it's `usort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callbacks are context aware and you can see that there are some bugs around it, like:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62547

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63468

But it is being fixed and therefore is supported :)

Answer (score 0):

Very strange.  I played around with it a bit dropping stack traces inside the callback.  Thought maybe it was the static calls that were letting it play loose with visibility, but:

```
class MyClass
{
  private static $data = array( 'banana', 'cherry', 'apple' );

  private function sort_by_text( $first, $second ) {
    return strcasecmp( $first, $second );
  }

  public function sorted_data() {
    usort( self::$data, array( __CLASS__, 'sort_by_text' ) );
    return self::$data;
  }
}

class MyClass2
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $mc = new MyClass();
    print_r($mc->sorted_data());
  }
}

$bleh = new MyClass2();
```

This works too, and the call stack looks as it should.  That's PHP for you.  Of course, I'd forgo the whole mess and just use a closure now.

Answer (score 0):

`usort` and other functions like `array_map` are actually context aware; if you use a non-public callback within a class, it works just fine. It's not like that method is being called from outside the class, it's just indirectly invoked via a callback, and that is a supported use case.

Comment: Can you show documentation of this behaviour? I have tried to search, but could not find direct description of it.